# Stream to Sony TV

Tags: streaming

Back when I used PopcornTime, I was able to select my TV and the movie started playing on that device without any further action. I would like to achieve the same result with regular files.

I know services like MediaTomb and ReadyMedia can stream, and I already set that up, but they require me to explicitly choose the file from the TV, which can be a pain.

I was wondering what -preferably free- protocol/software would be able to control the device that way.